# Object not instantiated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, object, odbc

I get the following error when running this code. I am trying to query data out of my SQL database using parameters and appear to have most everything I need, but I can't quite figure out the error on this one. My debugging attempts have failed:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
Option Strict Off
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim thisConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=myserver;Database=myDatabase;User  Id=username;Password=password")
Dim DBCommand As SqlCommand
Dim myReader As SqlDataReader

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Try

        thisConnection.Open()
        Console.WriteLine("Connect Open")
        DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOld", "20151215")
        DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateNew", "20151231")
        Dim myReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim fNextResult As Boolean = True
        Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\Documents\MomInt.txt"
        DBCommand = New SqlCommand("*****SQL code*****")



        Dim outputStream As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileName)

        'Get all values from the current item on the reader as long asRead() returns true...
        Do While myReader.Read
        'make an array the length of the available fields
        Dim values(myReader.FieldCount - 1) As Object
        'get all the field values
        myReader.GetValues(values)

        'write the text version of each value to a comma seperated string
        Dim line As String = String.Join(",", values)
        'write the csv line to the file
        outputStream.WriteLine(line)
        Loop
        myReader.Close()
             outputStream.Close()

        Me.Text = "Success!"
        Me.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse()
        thisConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Connection Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore)




    End Try
End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Run in debug mode, line by line, and see what line have a not instantiated object,

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you appear to using parameterized sql instead of stored procedures. This is ok but you are also using AddWithValue which can produce some very interesting and incorrect parameters. It would be better in these cases to explicitly name the datatype. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: You need to properly handle your database connections. The way you have this coded you are not properly disposing of the connection which is going to cause problems with the connection pool. The Close method needs to be inside of a finally to ensure it ALWAYS gets closed.

Comment: What language is this, VB.Net, VBScript? Please tag appropriately. Some of us SQL'ers might arrive to tackle queries only to be disappointed.